# WinAPI - How to print text to edit control?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, codeblocks

REVISION 1:

I can't get a good grip on WinAPI's `AllocConsole();` function. I either need option one, or option 2. It's better to have both though :). Thanks in advance. Here's option 1:

Make a console window from a WinAPI program when BUTTON_1 is clicked. The console needs to be able to output text (like `cout`), and sleep/delay text from being printed. (Something like `Sleep()`)

Option 2:

Instead of printing text to the console window like in option 1, the program prints text to a user-inaccessible editbox. This also needs to be able to use something like `Sleep()` to delay text from being printed.

Comment: You mean replacing it, like with `SetWindowText` or `WM_SETTEXT`?

Comment: SetWindowText().  This is very basic, you'll need to read Petzold's Programming Windows if you want to get ahead with native winapi programming.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're appending strings to an edit control, perhaps to record TTY-style output from some lengthy process:

Use the `EM_SETSEL` message to select the range just after the last character, then use `EM_REPLACESEL` to replace it with the string to append. The edit control scrolls when this happens. For example, if `hEdit` is the handle for the edit control, and `str` the 0-terminated string to append:

```
int idx=GetWindowTextLength(hEdit);
SendMessage(hEdit,EM_SETSEL,idx,idx);

SendMessage(hEdit,EM_REPLACESEL,0,(LPARAM)str);
```

This is the process recommended by this Knowledge Base article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109550

Comment: What if I need to use a function like Sleep(); to temporarily slow down the strings from being written to the edit box?

Comment: I don't think you'd need to do that for the edit box's sake, but if you need to do it for some other reason then you could. (No guarantees the list box will be updated, though, if the thread with the message loop is sleeping rather than pumping messages.)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions is to use

```
SendMessage(hEditBox,EM_SETSEL,-2,-2);
```

to move the caret to the end of text in the edit control. It saves you one function call and it works.

About the Sleep related part, I think it would be better to use timers, that should work without any problems.

Ex.

```
// somewhere in the code where you decide to make changes to the edit control
...
SetTimer(hWnd,TIMER_ID,1000,0);  // TIMER_ID is arbitrary, the delay is set to 1000 ms
...

// main procedure message 
switch (uMsg) {
   ...
   case WM_TIMER:
      SendMessage(hEditBox,EM_SETSEL,-2,-2);
      SendMessage(hEditBox,EM_REPLACESEL,0,buffer);
      KillTimer(hWnds,TIMER_ID);
   ...
}
```

You may want to put a bit more work into this, for instance to reuse the SetTimer call.

Comment: The -2 is a new one to me! Where is this documented?

Comment: Updated question to better fit my real problem. Your code above doesn't work for me because I don't know what to define `buffer` as. I know it's an `int`, but I don't know if it needs a specific number or not.

Comment: @TomSeddon it's not documented, I tried it and it worked. If you put 0FFFFFFFFh (-1) it's treated as -1 and as such it doesn't select anything. If you put 0FFFFFFFEh (-2) it seems to be treated as caret position of 4294967294 which ends up placing the caret on the end of the edit box text.

Comment: @Mike, buffer is not an integer, but a string buffer. It's basically the text you want to append to the edit control.